# Xcode: Add attachment using picker to email

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, email-attachments

I have developed an app that allows the user to choose a video from the photo gallery and send it as an attachment in an email. I am able to choose a video from the gallery and proceed with sending the email but the video does not get attached with the email. There are no errors in the console.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
- (IBAction)choose:(id)sender;


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
if (![UIImagePickerController  isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

    UIAlertController *myAlertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"MyTitle"
                                                                                message: @"MyMessage"
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert                   ];

    [self presentViewController:myAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)choose:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }


 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


[self performSelector:@selector(email:) withObject:chosenImage afterDelay:0.5];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)email:(UIImage *)choosenImage{
NSString *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSString *version = @"1.0";
NSString *build = @"100";
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"support@myappworks.com",nil]];
[mailComposer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"MailMe V%@ (build %@) Support",version,build]];
NSString *supportText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device: %@\niOS Version:%@\n\n",model,iOSVersion];
supportText = [supportText stringByAppendingString: @"Please describe your problem or question."];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(choosenImage);


[mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@""];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you're trying to attach a video, and you've configured your UIImagePickerController to limit the mediaTypes to only videos. The problem then is that you're asking for the "edited image" in the "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" method:

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

The user did not pick an image - they picked a video. You need to use this instead:

```
NSURL *chosenVideoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chosenVideoUrl];
```

You can then pass the videoData to your email method and attach to the email. Be sure to update the mimeType from "image/png" to "video/mp4", as well.

Comment: ive added the coding as u said..but im getting error: Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'NSURL * _Nonnull' at NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chosenVideoUrl];...

Comment: ive managed to solve it..i had to change: - (void)email:(UIImage *)choosenImage{ to - (void)email:(**NSURL***)choosenImage{
thank you so much for your help..@Ryan LaNeve

Comment: Sounds like you missed updating one of your UIImage usages. There shouldn't be any once you've made the changes.

Comment: yea..removed all the UIImages..its working fine now..thank you :) @Ryan LeNeve

Answer (score 1):

If u need to attach both video and image you have write to code for both,but you written only for attaching an image.You can try the code below for getting both

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqual:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        NSString *videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        [self emailImage:nil orVideo:videoURL];
    }else {
        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [self emailImage:chosenImage orVideo:nil];
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

`UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` will return file url unlike `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` ,so can use `NSData` method `dataWithContentsOfFile` as bellow.

```
if (choosenImage) {
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(choosenImage);
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%@.png",TimeStamp];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:filename];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}else {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoFile];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video_%@.mp4",TimeStamp];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:filename];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

it will be good if you give a filename for the attachment it will be help full after it downloading.if you wish you can use a TimeStamp for that.

```
#define TimeStamp [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]
```

Comment: Thank you @Shabeer Ali..this is helpful.